# Get the value that is returned from a method that is called from a constructor in the same class in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class with a constructor that is calling a method. This method is returning a double, is it somehow possible to get the methods return value outside the class?

Consider a class like this:

```
SampleClass::SampleClass() {
    SampleMethod(); //This method is returning a double
}
```

From main I would then somehow get the value that the method returns and store it in a double.

```
int main(){
    double val = SampleClass sample;
}
```

This is not possible as I have done in the code snippetbut I would like to do it in some similiar way.

I could do it like this:

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(double &val) {
    val = SampleMethod(); //This method is returning a double
}
```

and then call it from main like this:

```
int main(){

    double val{0}
    SampleClass sample(val);
}
```

But this forces me to have a constructor that needs parameters but I would like to have a constructor that does not take any arguments. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Is this possible to achieve?"_ No, it isn't. Constructor functions don't have a return value. Use a reference parameter if you need to capture the side effects result. It sounds you likely have a XY-problem, can you elaborate more about the use case you want to solve please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In the real case the return value of my method is "std::vector<std::vector<DdsClass>> " and I didn't want to have a constructor taking such a long parametername when I could just use "auto" in my main function. After second thoughts it maybe would have been more appropriate to put this question in the code review section, since the problem indeed is solvable with reference types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors can't return a value.

However, you can use a global variable if you like.

Ugly but does the job.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double ret;

struct SampleClass{
    SampleClass(){
        ret=magicFunction();
    }
    double magicFunction(){
        return 2.5;
    }
};

int main() {
    SampleClass sample;
    std::cout<<ret;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, as constructors cannot return a value.

What you can do is store it elsewhere. As we're talking about creating objects here, an obvious solution seems to store the result in the object. That'll make your object larger of course.

```
class SampleClass {
public:
  SampleClass()
  {
    result = SampleMethod();
  }
  double SampleMethod()
  {
    return 12.34;
  }
  double GetResult()
  {
    return result;
  }
private:
  double result;
}
```

So then you can do this:

```
int main() {
    SampleClass sample;
    double val = sample.GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ constructor can't return a value. Prevented by language design.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need return something from constructor. In C++ you must write right class that can copy and return values of needed type. Simple sample:

```
 class SampleClass
 {
     double _Value;
     double method ()
      {
          _Value *= 10; // Do something
          return _Value;
      }
 public:
     double operator = (double _v) 
      {
         _Value = _v; return _Value;
      }
     operator double () 
      {
          return method();
      }
 };
```

Using sample:

```
SampleClass a;
a = 1.1;
double b = a;
```